# DataTrigger inside a MultiDataTrigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change 2 Properties on 2 different conditions using Multi-/DataTrigger.

I have 1 Button which changes its `IsEnabled` Property when `ValidationRule` returns an error.

I also want to change the `Command` Property of this Button but on other conditions.

```
<Button Content="Save">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=FirstNameBox}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=LastNameBox}" Value="False" />
                            [...]
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Now I want to implement another Trigger which changes the `Binding` of the `Command` Property when anoither Propertie's Binding equals to XY.
So i need to implement this next to the Datatrigger above.

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding CreateEmployeeCommand}" />
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentManageMode}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding EditEmployeeCommand}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

So is it even possible to have 2 Triggers at the same time?

Comment: do you want to change the Binding of Command when IsEnabled true?

Comment: of course it is possible to have many triggers. `<Style.Triggers>` is a collection for reason

Comment: Add another condition to the MultiDataTrigger. There is no such thing as a DataTrigger inside a MultiDataTrigger.

Comment: @UsmanAli No I want to have both Triggers enabled. So Command binding has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: @mm8 But how will it work to add another Condition ? I want another result then i have no. Now i have "if some value returns false set IsEnabled to false". But next to that i want "if managemode == 1 set command to X if managemode != 1 set command to Y".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i fixed it adding another Trigger just in `Style.Triggers`.
I didn't tried this cuz many Controls/Properties doesn't allow multiple `Content`.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding CreateEmployeeCommand}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentManageMode}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding EditEmployeeCommand}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=FirstNameBox}" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=LastNameBox}" Value="False" />
                 </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
             </MultiDataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</Button.Style>
```